# Get source of Typescript runtime exception within Visual Studio Code

Tags: debugging, typescript, visual-studio-code

Looking for help to pinpoint exceptions in Visual Studio Code as they occur while debugging a Typescript app.  Most of the run-time exceptions are something like the following, which while useful, force me to guess where the actual error occurred:

*ERROR TypeError {ngDebugcontext: DebugContext_, message: "Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined"}*

Is there anyway to get a stacktrace or something similar?

Comment: I'd be using Chrome, right click and go to Inspect, then look at console tab. Then you can go to sources and call stack - and set breakpoints in VS Code.